# Angular router.events.subcribe is not working when route is changing

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router

I am using angular 6 and I am using router.events.subcribe in app component .when route is changing the subscribe is not triggering..

Comment: please post the code so that we can take a look and help

Answer (score 0):

Here's a typical implementation for `router.events.subscribe`

You put the subscription in `ngOnInit`

Notice it is not triggered when `ngOnInit` is called only when the route changes thereafter so you typically need to call your doSomething() method inside `ngOnInit` also

```
ngOnInit() {
  console.log('hello1')
  this.doSomething()
  this.router.events.subscribe((event) => {
    console.log('hello2')
    if (event instanceof NavigationEnd) {
      this.doSomething()
    }
  })
}
```

Comment: NavigationEnd calling multiple times when route is cahnging.